# check box should like radio buttons in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a requirement like check box should work like radio buttons.

I arranged check box programmatically with respect to array (if array size is 10, 10 check boxes are placed programmatically).

If one check box is checked others should be unchecked (should work like radio buttons).

After the check box is clicked the check box id should generate.

Please give me an idea.

Thanks,
UdaySekhar

Answer (score 7):

```
<RadioButton style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox" />`
```

This is how you can get the look of checkbox

Answer (score 4):

Give a common implementation of OnCheckChangeListener() to each of your checkboxes.

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {  
   @override  
    onCheckedChange((CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){  
             int id = buttonView.getId();  
               int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.cb1,R.id.cb2 .....R.id.cb10};    
               for (int i=0;i<10;i++){    
                   CheckBox cb =(CheckBox)view.findViewById(ids[i]);  
                   if(id==ids[i]{  
                       cb.setChecked(isChecked);}  
                   else  
                       cb.setChecked(false);         
               }  
};
```

view is the View object.
Hope this helps

Comment: its working, but you need to set onClickListner otherwise it will do a recursive call when you set the cb.setCheckted to some value

Answer (score 1):

just add a style in your checkbox

```
style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
```

**or**

if you want to change radio button work as checkbox then just add below line into your xml

```
style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
```